# Does the Champion's Tablet sums offerings from all characters?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Does the [Champion's Tablet](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Champion%27s+Tablet) shows the sum of offerings from all players characters or only from one character?

I.e. if I have two characters, one has offered 200 Awe Stones, and another one - 199 Awe Stones, will the Tablet show my score of 200 or 399?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like every Covenant, item collection is per character. Creating a new character means that you will need to start again.